How can I create a site template which includes a document library with a folder structure
I would like to create a site template which includes a document library with a folder structure.
I have tried using Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb but it only creates the document library not the folder schema structure.
My requirement is that I  want the users with access to be able to create the site using the template and prefarable via SharePoint > Select a template > from your organisation.
It seems PNP Powershell can do the job but my users won't e ableto use powershell.
Any suggestions to do this?
Thanks in advance
